# Find words inside dict-list

Tags: list, dictionary, for-loop

#I need to print if i found problem='FRAUDED BILL' or another phrase inside of those dict and print your respective key, (ex: EP1_2) for FRAUDED BILL

```
dict_ep = {'EP1_2':['FRAUDED BILL','IMPROPER BILLING - FRAUDED CARD (CARDS)','EMBEZZLEMENT','FRAUD'], 
            'EP1_4':['2nd COPY OF CONTRACT (CONSIGNEE)','ACCIDENT WITH DISPOSED VEHICLE'],
            'EP1_6':['BANK STRIKE'],
            'EP1_8':['ACCESS TO BALANCE AND CARD LIMIT','PAYMENT AGREEMENT']}

problem = ('frauded bill').upper()


for i in dict_ep:
    if problem == dict_ep.keys():
        print('EP found')
    else:
        print('EP no exist, try again!')
```

RESULTS:

```
EP no exist, try again!
EP no exist, try again!
EP no exist, try again!
EP no exist, try again!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `any()` to test if the string is found in list:

```py
dict_ep = {
    "EP1_2": [
        "FRAUDED BILL",
        "IMPROPER BILLING - FRAUDED CARD (CARDS)",
        "EMBEZZLEMENT",
        "FRAUD",
    ],
    "EP1_4": [
        "2nd COPY OF CONTRACT (CONSIGNEE)",
        "ACCIDENT WITH DISPOSED VEHICLE",
    ],
    "EP1_6": ["BANK STRIKE"],
    "EP1_8": ["ACCESS TO BALANCE AND CARD LIMIT", "PAYMENT AGREEMENT"],
}

problem = "frauded bill".upper()

for key, lst in dict_ep.items():
    if any(problem in v for v in lst):
        print("EP Found:", key)
    else:
        print("EP NOT Found:", key)
```

Prints:

```
EP Found: EP1_2
EP NOT Found: EP1_4
EP NOT Found: EP1_6
EP NOT Found: EP1_8
```

Comment: It's useful but, if i put just 'card'  the program show me in more than one dict